# jQuery FullCalendar - trying to add event and display on calendar failed

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to work out how to use Adam Shaw's brilliant jQuery plugin - FullCalendar to add an event on our project : [online balloon ordering page under development](http://development.accedo.com.au/balloon)

Basically, if you click on "step1" and choose "pickup in shop" , the page will bring you to the calendar view, where you could click on the upper-right corner at the "week" button
to alter the view to a weekly basis. What I am trying to achieve is when client clicks on an empty slot in a day, she can create her event on that spot. Here is my code in custom.js:

```
dayClick: function() 
            {

                var n = parseInt(this.className.match(/fc\-slot(\d+)/)[1]);
                alert('a day has been clicked on slot ' + n);

                //trying to add an event using the renderEvent() method.
                $('#' + type + 'Calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', 
                        {
                            title : 'my pickup slot',
                            start : new Date(y,m,d, 12, 30),
                            end   : new Date(y,m,d, 13, 00),
                        });
            }
```

It tries to use the FullCalendar's API method [renderEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) so to create such an event. However, although my code runs without error and I can see the prompt saying which slot has been clicked, It wouldn't render such an new event on calendar.

Is there another way to do this or my code does something wrong?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: the CarnivalAndToy is your project? You should completly rethink what are you doing! So many click to order something? You need to know that every commerce site is great for a One Step Checkout, not 101 ... (I'm just saying as I'm in the business - www.cattier.dk )

Comment: @balexandre : Yes, it is our project. It is for the CarnivalAndToy.com.au and currently under development in accedo.com.au. It takes us much time already to complete such a way and already got confirmed by the client - boss of CarnivalAndToy.com.cu

Yeah, user interface is a bit awkward and complicated, I wish there would be only one button "buy balloons", but unfortunately, that would not work according to the requirements.
Anyway, thanks for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple oversight. The value of `type` in the function `loadCalender(type)` is set to `pickupCalendar` from the call `closeStep1OpenSetp2("pickupCalendar");`.

But you do `$('#' + type + 'Calendar')` which evaluates to `$('#pickupCalendarCalendar')` and there is no element with this id. Correct would be `$('#pickupCalendar')` so either remove Calendar in the parameter or ditch the `+ 'Calendar'`. Then it should work just fine

Comment: @jitter : Thanks so much for this picking up! OMG, I never realize that I have made such a mistake in code... Overnight development...
I could not give you more than one up-vote, which is so sad :)